# Guest OS instantly shutting down Google Cloud instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gcloud

I have uploaded a few VM's to Google cloud instance. Whenever I start them they instantly shut down. I am not able to SSH or see output from the serial port. The logs tell me the GuestOS has requested shut down. Is here any way to see why this is? The VM's work fine in ESXI.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there! I have some questions regarding your issue: how you imported the VM to GCP? Did you follow a guide or document? Did you install GCE Guest environment? What version of OS do you have?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reaction. I am both using Debian 9 and CentOS 8. I have used the GCP guide from Google theirselves. Found at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks. The docs say the Guest environment is installed automatically, or maybe I am mistaken?

Comment: As per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment#centosrhel_2),  you do not need to manually install a guest environment if you are using the VM instances that are created using Google-provided public images. If not, then, you have to manually install the guest environment.

Comment: That should be it then. I'll give it a go, thanks!